# Where to keep static data fetched from external json file React

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

Currently I wonder where/how should I keep static data which I am getting from external source(json).
So more precisely I am working with riot api. And I am in point where I am fetching information about last 10-20 games. In this fetched data I get something like this:

```
{
 gameId: 125,
 championId: 12,
 timestamp: xxxx,
 role: BOTTOM
},
{
 gameId: 121231,
 championId: 1,
 timestamp: xxxx,
 role: BOTTOM
}
```

And from this, what is the most importent is `championId` by which I can find particular champion info from http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json

As you can see in this json all champion data are stored. So best thing would be to store it as static variable in some place on client side. But I am not sure what is the best place I was thinking about storing it in top level compoment state, but it seems stupid(?). Another idea was to foreach match data fetch data from this json url, and than return champion data according to id, but is would require to do requests to champion.json url for each match data.

Any other ideas how that should be done?

Comment: *"I was thinking about storing it in top level compoment state, but it seems stupid(?)."* Why?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would need to pass it to every child node with the props. For me it bad design from Java expierience. Bur I might be wrong about this.

Comment: If you have to pass it deep, it starts being problematic, yeah. :-) That's why React added Context (#2 in my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several choices:

1. Save it as top-level component state, and pass it down to any components that need it.
2. Use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).
3. Put it in its own module that any component that needs it can request.

#3 is similar to what you wrote here:

> Another idea was to foreach match data fetch data from this json url, and than return champion data according to id, but is would require to do requests to champion.json url for each match data.

...but there's no need to re-request the data every time. Simply:

```
const matchDataPromise =
    fetch(/*...*/)
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
        }
        return res.json();
    });
export default matchDataPromise.
```

Any component that needs it would do:

```
import matchDataPromise from "./matchData.js";
```

and then in `componentDidMount`, consume the promise.

The data will only be fetched once, but each component would need to handle the fact that it gets the data asynchronously.